# CSS Style Menu issue with IE

Tags: html, asp.net, css, visual-studio, menu

I have a strange issue with an html CSS Responsive Menu and Internet Explorer.
If I see the html of the menu in internet explorer all seems fine in IE and Firefox with the right colors but If I insert the same html page in my ASP.NET webSite and I go by Internet Explorer using local  visual studio instance I see that the colors of the menu aren't red but are blu!! I'm only using the style of the menu.

> This is the HTML of the menu demo page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <title>Demo menu</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 13px
        }
    </style>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="js-css-menu.css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
    <p><b>Responsive CSS3 Menu with Dropdown (Horizontal and Vertical)</b></p>
    <ul class="js-css-menu shadow responsive">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="current"><a href="#">Current</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link with Menu</a>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><b>Col 1</b></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sublink 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sublink 3</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li><b>Col 2</b></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sublink 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sublink 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
    </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

---

> with this CSS style:

```
/* PRIMARY MENU style */
 .js-css-menu {
     font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
     font-size: 13px;
     border: 1px solid #900000;
     display: inline-block;
}
 .js-css-menu, .js-css-menu ul, .js-css-menu li {
     list-style: none;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
}
 .js-css-menu a {
     text-decoration: none;
     -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
     -ms-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
     transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
 .js-css-menu > li {
     display: inline-block;
     float: left;
}
 .js-css-menu > li > a {
     color: #fefefe;
     text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 maroon;
     background-color: #dd0000;
     background-image: linear-gradient(top, #dd0000 20%, #aa0000);
     background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #dd0000 20%, #aa0000);
     background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #dd0000 20%, #aa0000);
     background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #dd0000 20%, #aa0000);
     background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #dd0000 20%, #aa0000);
     background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#dd0000) 20%, to(#aa0000));
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr='$to', EndColorStr='$from');
     padding: 10px 15px;
     display: block;
}
 .js-css-menu > li:hover > a {
     background-color: #fa0000;
     background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fa0000 20%, #af0000);
     background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fa0000 20%, #af0000);
     background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fa0000 20%, #af0000);
     background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fa0000 20%, #af0000);
     background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fa0000 20%, #af0000);
     background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fa0000) 20%, to(#af0000));
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr='$to', EndColorStr='$from');
}
 .js-css-menu > li > a:active {
     background-color: #aa0000;
     background-image: linear-gradient(top, #aa0000 20%, #cc0000);
     background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #aa0000 20%, #cc0000);
     background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #aa0000 20%, #cc0000);
     background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #aa0000 20%, #cc0000);
     background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #aa0000 20%, #cc0000);
     background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#aa0000) 20%, to(#cc0000));
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr='$to', EndColorStr='$from');
     box-shadow: inset 0 1px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
     -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
 .js-css-menu > li.current > a {
     background-color: #880000;
     background-image: linear-gradient(top, #880000 20%, #aa0000);
     background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #880000 20%, #aa0000);
     background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #880000 20%, #aa0000);
     background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #880000 20%, #aa0000);
     background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #880000 20%, #aa0000);
     background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#880000) 20%, to(#aa0000));
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr='$to', EndColorStr='$from');
     box-shadow: inset 0 1px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
     -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
/* SUBMENU */
 .js-css-menu > li div {
     border-top: 1px solid #900000;
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     visibility: hidden;
     opacity: 0;
     -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
     -ms-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
     transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
 .js-css-menu > li div a {
     color: #ddd;
}
 .js-css-menu > li div a:hover, .js-css-menu > li div a:focus {
     color: #fefefe;
}
 .js-css-menu > li div ul {
     float: left;
}
 .js-css-menu > li div ul li {
     line-height: 1.5em;
}
 .js-css-menu > li div ul:not(:first-child) {
     margin-left: 20px;
}
 .js-css-menu > li:hover div, .js-css-menu > li:focus div {
     color: #fefefe;
     background: #b00000;
     padding: 10px 15px;
     visibility: visible;
     opacity: 1;
}
/* VERTICAL style */
 .js-css-menu.vertical {
     width: 100px;
    /* Adjust the width of the vertical menu */
}
 .js-css-menu.vertical > li {
     display: block;
     float: none;
     position: relative;
}
 .js-css-menu.vertical > li div {
     width: 150px;
     left: 101px;
    /* Adjust the left value according to the width of the vertical menu */
     top: 0;
}
/* ROUNDED style */
 .js-css-menu.rounded {
     border-radius: 3px;
     -moz-border-radius: 3px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}
 .js-css-menu.rounded > li:first-child > a {
     border-top-left-radius: 2px;
     -moz-border-radius-topleft: 2px;
     -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 2px;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
     -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 2px;
     -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
}
 .js-css-menu.rounded > li:last-child > a {
     border-top-right-radius: 2px;
     -moz-border-radius-topright: 2px;
     -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 2px;
     border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
     -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 2px;
     -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
}
 .js-css-menu.rounded > li div {
     border-radius: 3px;
     -moz-border-radius: 3px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
     border-top-left-radius: 0;
     -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0;
     -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0;
}
 .js-css-menu.rounded.vertical > li:first-child > a {
     border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
     -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0;
     -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
     border-top-right-radius: 2px;
     -moz-border-radius-topright: 2px;
     -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 2px;
}
 .js-css-menu.rounded.vertical > li:last-child > a {
     border-top-right-radius: 0;
     -moz-border-radius-topright: 0;
     -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
     -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 2px;
     -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
}
/* SHADOW style */
 .js-css-menu.shadow, .js-css-menu.shadow div {
     box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
/* RESPONSIVE style */
 @media (max-width: 480px) {
    /* To adjust the "breaking point" of the responsive menu, change 480px to a value of your choosing. */
     .js-css-menu.responsive, .js-css-menu.responsive > li {
         width: auto!important;
         display: block;
         float: none;
    }
     .js-css-menu.responsive > li:first-child > a {
         border-bottom-left-radius: 0 !important;
         -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0 !important;
         -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0 !important;
         border-bottom-right-radius: 0 !important;
         -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0 !important;
         -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0 !important;
    }
     .js-css-menu.responsive > li:last-child > a {
         border-top-left-radius: 0 !important;
         -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0 !important;
         -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0 !important;
         border-top-right-radius: 0 !important;
         -moz-border-radius-topright: 0 !important;
         -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0 !important;
    }
     .js-css-menu.responsive > li div {
         display: none!important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use developer tools to detect which styles are applied. There is 'Trace styles' tab, where you can see all rules applied to selected node.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't set a standard CSS Link colour so it's setting it to the generic blue.

add this to your CSS with what ever colour you want your links to be:

```
a:link {color: #FF0000; text-decoration: none;}

a:hover {color: #FF0000;text-decoration: none;}

a:active {color: #FF0000;text-decoration: none;}

a:visited {color: #FF0000; text-decoration: none;}
```

Comment: This is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/XMKmQ/ try it in firefox and in IE. As you can see in Firefox is red but in IE is blu

Answer (score 2):

There is a unclosed bracket in your `HTML` code.

✮✮ **ALWAYS** ✮✮ [validate](https://validator.w3.org/) your code to ensure there are not typo error!

See the [working demo](http://jsbin.com/polome/edit?html,css,output).